# .git takes MORE space after gc

Tags: disk-usage, git

```
$ du -ks .git
784113  .git
$ git gc
Counting objects: 30237, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9165/9165), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30237/30237), done.
Total 30237 (delta 19514), reused 30077 (delta 19414)
$ du -ks .git
939785  .git
```

I would have expected that after a `gc`, the .git directory is either smaller or has the same size as before, but not that it grows by nearly 20%. How can this be explained?

Comment: @user1934428 what does `ls .git .git/objects` show? You might have some temporary files left over from a previous, interrupted, `git gc`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Even if it were so, they would have been before. As you can se, I checked the directory size, then run `git gc` once, and then checked the size again - immediately after. I don't see how between the two size checks, temporary files could sneak in, if I do *only* a gc and nothing else. The directory contains: *.git:* COMMIT_EDITMSG FETCH_HEAD HEAD ORIG_HEAD config description hooks index info logs modules objects packed-refs refs *.git/objects:* 03 0f 14 17 18 1d 2e 34 45 46 5b 61 66 6e 72 78 7c 81 86 89 92 94 97 b0 b1 b5 b8 bc ca cb ce de e1 e2 ea ef f3 f9 fb fe info pack

Comment: yes, you’re right, temporary files would only explain the size increase if they were left over from this particular `git gc` run.

Comment: Add `--aggressive`. Also what is the value of option `gc.auto` in your config file, if any?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek : I am reluctant to use `--aggressive`, because it seems to cause undesirable side effects, at least sometimes. See for instance [here](https://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/). I have not set `gc.auto`, so this option must have its default value. `git config --get gc.auto` doesn't show anything.